# Clean URL using regex and .htaccess & mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using below code on my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /view_basket.php?order_id=$1&pin=$2 [L]
```

the goal is to redirect a clean URL like below

```
http://www.zire20.ir/77438/9512
```

to this one

```
http://www.zire20.ir/view_basket.php?order_id=77438&pin=9512
```

The thing is it was working on my previous server but now I changed to godaddy hosting and it's not working! any idea ?

p.s:

and my whole .htaccess file is like below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zire20.ir [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.zire20.ir/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /view_basket.php?order_id=$1&pin=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Maybe you need to add `#Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews` (see [this article](https://davidwalsh.name/mod_rewrite-htaccess-godaddy))

Comment: First what do you mean by `it's not working`. Are you getting errors or it's behaving differently then expected. .

Comment: You are right I should explained, it's causing abnormal behaviors in website, lots of photos are not loading! @panama jack

Comment: Have you tried `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.zire20.ir [NC]` ?

Comment: @Wiktor I tried this one but didn't work!

Comment: @Pedro , It didn't work!

Comment: can you try just this: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /view_basket.php?order_id=$1&pin=$2 [L]` does it work ?

Comment: @Pedro Lobito , I tried this one also, same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /view_basket.php?order_id=$1&pin=$2 [L]`
>   lots of photos are not loading!

The problem with your current rule is that you are rewriting *unconditionally*. Any URL that contains a single slash will get rewritten. I imagine that some of your (static) photo URLs match this pattern.

Common practise is to only rewrite the URL if it doesn't match an existing file (or directory):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /view_basket.php?order_id=$1&pin=$2 [L]
```

This makes sure the request is only rewritten for non-existing files (not a file or a directory). I've also made the pattern a little more restrictive so there must be 1 or more chars before and after the slash (`+`), instead of 0 or more (`*`).

> The thing is it was working on my previous server

I can't see how this was possible, unless the URL structure was different on the previous server?